# Indexing strings with an specific length inside

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of names which looks like this:

```
c("xxxxxx xx",             "xxx yyy xxxxx",       "xxx yy xxxxxx", 
  "xxxxxxx yyyyyyy xxxxx", "xxxx xxxx",           "xxx yyyyyy xxx", 
  "xxxxx yyyyy xxxxxxxx",  "xxx yyyyyyyy xxxx",   "xx xxx", 
  "xxxxx yyyyy xxxxx",     "xxxx yy xxxxxx",      "xxxxx yyyy xxx", 
  "xxxxxxx yy xxxxx",      "xxxxx yyyyyyy xxxxx", "xxxx yyyy xxxxxx", 
  "xxxxx yyyy xxxxx",      "xxxxxxxx  xxxxx",     "xxxxxx yyyyyyyy xxxxx", 
  "xxxxxx yy xxxxx",       "xxx yyyy xxxxxx")
```

I need to extract (index) all those names with word of 4-6 letters.

I know that I could `split` each string, calculate their number of characters with `nchar` and then index which ones have a length between 2 and 4. But, is there any way to do that with a single line using **regular expressions**?

The expected output must be a vector:
Numeric

```
[1]  1  2  3  5  6  8  9 11 12 13 15 16 20
```

Or logical

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
[11] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `\S{4,6}` or `[ your valid letters ]{4,6}` or `[a-zA-Z]{4,6}`

Comment: @sln I have tried your code and it does not return the correct answer??

Comment: Do you want that _ALL_ words have 4-6 letters or _there is at least one word_ with 4-6 letters?  Your proposed answer does not agree with either description.

Comment: What is `the correct answer` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Base R**
You can use `grepl`

```
grepl("\\b\\w{4,6}\\b", my.text)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

**stringr**
You can use `stringr`'s `str_detect` with

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(my.text, "\\b\\w{4,6}\\b")
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

In both versions the keypoint is the regular expression which matches words of length 4 to 6. `\\b` indicates a word boundary. `\\w` matches any word characters; `[A-z0-9_]`. If you only want to match letters you can use `[A-z]` or `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\\w`.

**Data**

```
my.text <- c("xxxxxx xx", "xxx yyy xxxxx", "xxx yy xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx yyyyyyy xxxxx", 
             "xxxx xxxx", "xxx yyyyyy xxx", "xxxxx yyyyy xxxxxxxx","xxx yyyyyyyy xxxx", "xx xxx")
```

Comment: I don't think this will totally work, because It'll return `TRUE` for words that are greater than 6.